# moment divide time into chunks based on dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have two dates like below

```
2016-02-18T22:00:00+00:00 - 2016-02-19T02:00:00+00:00
```

These are the start and end dates I'm getting

here I want to divide the dates into two ranges like below

```
2016-02-18T22:00:00+00:00 - 2016-02-19T00:00:00+00:00
2016-02-19T00:00:00+00:00 - 2016-02-19T02:00:00+00:00
```

I'm using momentjs library, any help here?

I'm able to get the difference between two dates using following

```
moment(b).startOf('day').diff(moment(a).startOf('day'),'days')
```

but don't know how to proceed from here

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre updated, I'm able to get the difference between dates but don't know how to proceed from there

Answer (score 3):

Using diff() function is a good idea and then just play with milliseconds result, I would do:

- compute diff of 2 dates : milliseconds
- compute half of diff
- add half of diff to first date

https://jsfiddle.net/darul75/ot3p1ytj/2/

```
    var first = moment.utc('2016-02-18T22:00:00+00:00');
    var second = moment.utc('2016-02-19T02:00:00+00:00');    

    // compute diff in ms
    var diffInMs = Math.abs(moment(first).diff(second));
    // half
    var middleGap = diffInMs / 2;

    var middleDate = moment(first).add(middleGap, 'ms');`
```

Comment: can you be more specific with some scenarios

Comment: just try to  change start time to `2016-02-18T21:00:00+00:00` and it is not working